# Цвет фона в pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qss

Подскажите, как можно изменить цвет фона? 
Пытаюсь изменить с помощью `setStyleSheet`, он меняется, но настройка шрифта сбивается.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ClassesPage1(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClassesPage1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setTitle("...")
        self.setSubTitle("...")

        #self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(100, 133, 202);")

        self.checkBox_1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('...')
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('...')
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('...')
        self.checkBox_4 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('...')

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.checkBox_1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.checkBox_2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.checkBox_3)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.checkBox_4)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.checkBox_1.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        self.checkBox_2.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        self.checkBox_3.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        self.checkBox_4.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        
        self.listCheckBox = [self.checkBox_1, self.checkBox_2, self.checkBox_3, self.checkBox_4] 
        self.a = 0                                                                                    

    def check(self, state):
        self.a = 0                                               
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            a = a + 1
        for checkBox in self.listCheckBox:                       
            if checkBox.isChecked():                              
                self.a += 1                                      
        print(self.a)

    def nextId(self):
        return Wizard.class4
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ClassesPage1()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из вашего примера я не понял настройка какого шрифта сбивается? Пожалуйста, в следующий раз постарайтесь показать, что вы хотите получить в итоге.

А пока вот некоторая реализация `StyleSheet` для `QCheckBox`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ClassesPage1(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClassesPage1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setTitle("...")
        self.setSubTitle("...")
#        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(100, 133, 202);")

        self.checkBox_1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('cb1 ...')
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('cb2 ...')
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('cb3 ...')
        self.checkBox_4 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('cb4 ...')

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.checkBox_1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.checkBox_2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.checkBox_3)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.checkBox_4)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.checkBox_1.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        self.checkBox_2.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        self.checkBox_3.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        self.checkBox_4.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        
        self.listCheckBox = [self.checkBox_1, self.checkBox_2, self.checkBox_3, self.checkBox_4] 
        self.a = 0                                                                                    

    def check(self, state):
        self.a = 0                                               
# ?        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
# ?            a = a + 1
        for checkBox in self.listCheckBox:                       
            if checkBox.isChecked():                              
                self.a += 1                                      
        print(self.a)

    def nextId(self):
        return Wizard.class4
        
        
StyleSheet = '''
QWizardPage {
    background-color: rgb(100, 133, 202);
}
QCheckBox {
    spacing: 5px;
    font-size:25px;     
    background-color: rgb(200, 133, 202);
    
}
QCheckBox::indicator {
    width:  33px;
    height: 33px;
}
''' 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setStyle("fusion")                                                # +++              
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)                                         # +++ 
    
    w = ClassesPage1()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]